# If $x_{i+1} =x^2_i+x_i $and $x_1= \frac 12 ,\lfloor \sum_{i=1}^{n} {1 \over {x_i+1}}\rfloor=1$. Then n = 100/101/102/103

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If $x_{i+1} =x^2_i+x_i $and $x_1= \frac 12 ,$ $$\lfloor \sum_{i=1}^{n} {1 \over {x_i+1}}\rfloor=1.$$ Then for which of the following n does this condition hold ?
>
> (a)100
>
> (b)101
>
> (c)102
>
> (d)103

So in this question I have tried everything like tried to make a telescopic , writing down a few initial terms to guess a pattern, but nothing seems to be working. It's a question involving Greatest Integer Function  , so I have an intuitive feeling that maybe I don't actually have to evaluate this particular series, but something similar and then show an inequality over all the terms, but I couldn't think of anything else. Please help

Comment: All given $n$ work.  Are you sure that there is no mistake in the problem statement?

Comment: @WETutorialSchool There is no condition that all are not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $x_{i+1}=x_i^2+x_i$ we get
$$\frac1{x_{i+1}}=\frac{1}{x_i(x_i+1)}=\frac{1}{x_i}-\frac1{x_i+1}.$$
That is, $\frac1{x_i+1}=\frac1{x_i}-\frac1{x_{i+1}}$.  So by telescoping
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{x_i+1}=\frac1{x_1}-\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}=2-\frac1{x_{n+1}}.$$
Hence, for $n$ that is an answer to this question we need 
$$1\leq 2-\frac1{x_{n+1}}<2$$
or
$$x_{n+1}\geq 1.$$
But it can be shown that $x_3>1$ and since $(x_n)$ is an increasing sequence, we see that $x_{n+1}>1$ for all $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Thank You so so much